# Google Sheets moving to a new column if cell not blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to scan barcodes of inventory for techs to install I wanted to find a way to skip to the next column after I scan a certain number of meters for example: John needs 90 units his name is on A1 I start scanning at A2 and scan the 90 barcodes after it reaches A91 it hops to B2 so I can scan the 90 that tell next guy needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could teach a guy one of the shortcut keys:

- press and hold <kbd>**`PAGE UP`**</kbd>
- <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`HOME`**</kbd> and then <kbd>**`RIGHT ARROW`**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah shortcuts are cute and all my man but I'd rather try not to walk back and forth to the computer 84 times to just to switch columns that's the point of the question.